# How to use autoload method in active_support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

F:\app\a.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'

module A
  extend ActiveSupport::Autoload
  autoload :B,'F:\app\test\b'
end
```

F:\app\a\b.rb

```
module A
  class B
  end
end
```

in the irb:

```
require 'f:\app\a'
A::B
```

=> NameError: uninitialized constant A::B

Which place I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

When declaring an `autoload`, the specified path has to be relative to one in `$LOAD_PATH` or `$:`, the short-hand alias of same. Since `autoload` is built in to Ruby, it does not require ActiveSupport. The Autoload library actually does a bunch of other things not specifically related to that, basically making the `autoload` smarter but still functionally similar.

I don't think you're able to use absolute paths as you have here.

Usually you see these defined as:

```
autoload(:B, 'a/b')
```

This is because somewhere you've defined your load path:

```
$LOAD_PATH << 'F:\app'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using load instead of autoload.